# Not friends query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table `users(id,username)` and friends table as `friends(id,friend_one,friend_two,status)`.

Say I am logged in with user 1 whose id is 1 I want to fetch records who are not friends on user 1 and to whom user 1 has sent friend request. How can I do this. status = 1 means both users are friends and status = 0 means friend request is pending.

```
users(1,'A') 
users(2,'B')
users(3,'C')
users(4,'D')
users(5,'E')
```

Friends Table entries

```
friends(1,2,1)
friends(1,3,1)
friends(1,5,0)
```

Expected result

```
username ID status

D            4  
E       5    0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to work out your example data. I can't see where user D is coming from.

Taking your description of what you require (only the users who have been sent a friend request but where it is not accepted so status is 0):-

```
SELECT u2.username, u2.id, f.status
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN friends f
ON u1.id = f.friend_one
INNER JOIN users u2
ON f.friend_two = u2.id
WHERE u1.id = 1
AND f.status = 0
```

EDIT

Revised query to also include people to whom not friend request has been sent:-

```
SELECT u2.username, u2.id, f.status
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2
ON u1.id != u2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f
ON u1.id = f.friend_one
AND u2.id = f.friend_two
WHERE u1.id = 1
AND (f.status IS NULL
OR f.status = 0)
```

EDIT - further revised query if you want to check up for friend requests both ways:-

```
SELECT u2.username, u2.id, f.status
FROM users u1
INNER JOIN users u2
ON u1.id != u2.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN friends f
ON (u1.id = f.friend_one
AND u2.id = f.friend_two)
OR (u1.id = f.friend_two
AND u2.id = f.friend_one)
WHERE u1.id = 1
AND (f.status IS NULL
OR f.status = 0)
```

Comment: My question is to get list all person who are not friends of current user and also list of people to whom current user has sent the friends request. Your query is returning me the second part of my question.

Comment: Added a solution that does that for you. Test on SQL fiddle - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4e37/3

Comment: Please Try this solution Ajay should should come into the list

`CREATE TABLE users
(
 id INT,
 username VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE friends
(
 id INT,
 friend_one INT,
 friend_two INT,
 status INT
);

INSERT INTO users (id, username) VALUES
(1,'Abhimanyu') ,
(2,'Ajay'),
(3,'Ashish'),
(4,'Jayesh'),
(5,'Radha'),
(6,'Trupti'),
(7,'Parag');

INSERT INTO friends (id, friend_one, friend_two, status) VALUES
(1,1,4,1),
(2,1,3,1),
(3,2,1,1),
(3,1,6,0),
(3,1,5,0);`

Comment: With the solution I posted Ajay does come into the list - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a3a0f/1

Comment: Thats what my question is Ajay should not come into the list because he is friend of 1 as you see the entry (3,2,1,1). Ajay i.e. id = 2 should not come into the list.

Comment: Further solution added if you want to check irrespective of who sent who the friend request.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
SELECT users.username, friends.status 
FROM users LEFT JOIN friends on users.id = friends.fried_one 
WHERE users.id NOT IN (
    SELECT friends.friend_two WHERE friend_one = users.id AND status = 1
)
```

Comment: I also want status from friends table so I would have to use join or union

Comment: say i have user one logged who is having id 1 will the query would be like this
`SELECT users.username, friends.status 
FROM users LEFT JOIN friends on users.id = friends.fried_one 
WHERE 1 NOT IN (
    SELECT friends.friend_two WHERE friend_one = users.id AND status = 1
)`